# Should the [patron] tag be merged with the [warlock] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

There are currently 9 questions tagged [patron](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/patron) and all of them are also tagged [warlock](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/warlock). Do we really need a separate [patron](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/patron) tag?

Comment: This really makes me want to create a [meta-tag:folksonomy] meta tag =)

Comment: Uhm... the [patron] tag appears to no longer exist. Does that mean something was done to it?

Comment: @Someone_Evil seems so...?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we need a [patron] tag for questions that aren't about warlocks (for instance, wealthy patrons of adventuring parties), so no, we shouldn't merge the two, we should remove [patron] from the existing warlock questions.

Comment: We should then write up what we mean by the [patron] tag as all of the currently tagged questions are indeed about warlock patrons.

Comment: I agree with ZwiQ (both the overall Q and this comment); if [patron] means something else besides "something to do with a warlock", then it should be made explicit, because at the moment it just seems like a redundant tag that hangs off the [warlock] tag. Currently, there are no questions about wealthy patrons of adventuring parties or similar that require a patron tag, so it might be better to remove it and wait for such questions to be asked that would then need a [patron] tag.

Comment: If we do end up with a separate [patron] tag for non-warlock patrons, I can see it getting put on [warlock] questions again. We could prevent that at that time by making [warlock-patron] a synonym of [warlock], to catch most people who start typing “patron” in the tag field.